# SwiftUI ForEach loop does not reflect changes when the list changes state?

Tags: swiftui, foreach

I am still trying to understand exactly how @State, @ObservedObject, @Published, etc properties can help accomplish what I am trying to do. I have tried a variety of these in different ways with no change in my issue.

So right now I have two @State variables along with this for loop within my main view. The loop displays the views stored within the `eventViews` list with the frame and position specified in the `eventBounds` list.

```
struct CalendarDayView: View { 
    @State var eventViews: [CalendarEventView] = [] 
    @State var eventBounds: [CGRect] = [] 
    var body: some View { 
        ZStack { 
            ForEach(eventViews.indices, id: \.self) { index in     
                let eventView = eventViews[index] 
                let bounds =   eventBounds[index] 
                eventView          
                    .frame(width: bounds.width, 
                        height: bounds.height, 
                        alignment: .center) 
                    .position(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY) 
            } 
        } 
    }                
}
```

When the user makes changes to the events or their bounds I call a function `calculateEventBounds()` which goes through all the events and calculates the bounds I want them to be rendered with according to their positioning, etc. Everything works great, except when I call `calculateEventBounds()`, the changes made are only updated on the UI after I switch tabs on my app and go back to the CalendarDayView. I need the changes to be seen immediately after calling `calculateEventBounds()`.

How can I invalidate this for loop so that the changes to `eventViews` and `eventBounds` are seen immediately in the UI?

Here is simplified code for `calculateEventBounds()`:

```
func calculateEventBounds() { 
    self.eventViews = [] 
    self.eventBounds = [] 
    let events = eventsManager.getEventsOnDay(day: Int(day))         
    
    for event in events { //do fancy stuff to calculate the event's bounds 
        self.eventViews.append(CalendarEventView(event: event))   
        self.eventBounds.append(bounds) //bounds is a CGRect defined within the for loop 
    }
}
```

My struct `CalendarEventView` is a view that holds a `CalendarEvent` struct with the info of the CalendarEvent like it's name, start time, etc.

I've tried using a separate class that conforms to `ObservableObject` and holds the `eventViews` and `eventBounds` as @Published properties while storing that class as an `@ObservedObject` in my `CalendarDayView`, and the for loop would get the views from a getter function of the other class but that didn't solve my issue either.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider: 1) Formatting your code so that it is readable. 2) including a [mre]

Comment: formatting is fixed

Comment: You shouldn't be storing Views in a `@State` array, using `indices` in a `ForEach` or using `self` as the key for `ForEach`. Without a [mre], it's not possible to provide a complete solution, but in general, you may want to check out some SwiftUI tutorials to see how these patterns are commonly dealt with. Also may want to watch "Demystify SwiftUI" from WWDC.

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks for the response, I've been googling for hours trying to find solutions without much luck. I'll check out Demystify SwiftUI.

Comment: Views should never exist in arrays. It doesn’t work for a number is reasons. You can have an array of “EventModel” that can be used by an “EventView” but the views themselves cannot be used in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major bad practices, I even call them mistakes:

1. Multiple arrays as data source
2. SwiftUI view as part of the data source.

---

An event should be an `Event` struct containing the `bounds`, an `init` method for the event data and the method to calculate the bounds (is a grid or another intelligent collection view not a better choice?).

```
struct Event: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var bounds: CGRect = .zero 

    init(data: ...) { ... }

    calculateBounds() { ... }
}
```

Then use a View Model, a class conforming to `ObservableObject` – as you already tried – with a `@Published` property containing the events, and also a method to get the events and create `Event` instances

```
class EventManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var events = [Event]()

    func getEventsOnDay(day: Int) { 
       
        let eventData = // get the data        
        events = eventData.map { data in
            let event = Event(data: data)
            event.calculateBounds()
            return event
        }
    }
}
```

In the view create an instance of `EventManager` as `@StateObject` and get the events from there.

```
struct CalendarDayView: View { 
    @StateObject var manager = EventManager()
   
    var body: some View { 
        ZStack { 
            ForEach(manager.events) { event in
                let bounds = event.bounds 
                CalendarEventView(event: event)         
                    .frame(width: bounds.width, 
                        height: bounds.height, 
                        alignment: .center) 
                    .position(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY) 
            } 
        } 
    }                
}
```

In `onAppear` (or in asynchronous `task`) you can call the method to get the data.

Any change in the `events` array will trigger the view to refresh.